# HTTPURLConnection int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode(); returns -1

Tags: java, http

In the code below, `hConn.disconnect();` runs. I thought `responseCode` gets -1. How can I correct it?  Is `setRequestMethod("GET")` necessary?

```
public static void downloadFile(String fileURL, String saveDirectory)
            throws IOException {
        URL u = new URL(fileURL);
        HttpURLConnection hConn = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
        int responseCode = hConn.getResponseCode();


        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
           //some code here
           //some codes here
        } else {
            System.out.println("No file to download. Server replied HTTP code: " + responseCode);
        }
        hConn.disconnect();
    }
```

Comment: The [method documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getResponseCode--) suggests the HTTP response you're getting from that URL is not valid. Have you tried stepping through this with a debugger or trying the same request from outside Java?

Comment: This means that no response code could be found. Have tried sending the request with a browser tool or curl and check the response?

Comment: @PaulBenn Thanx, I will try

Comment: @ItFreak Thanx, I will try

Comment: no problem, you should add the result to your original post